# Python 2.7 version how do i check_output

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

```
result = check_output(['ocrad', fn + '.ppm']).strip().replace(' ', '')
```

is problem..

```
File "coding.ch17.py", line 55, in <module>
ch17()
File "coding.ch17.py", line 48, in ch17
result = solve_ch17(fn)
File "coding.ch17.py", line 35, in solve_ch17
result = check_output(['ocrad', fn + '.ppm']).strip().replace(' ', '')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

can your help me ?

Source code

```
def solve_ch17(fn):
    black, white = (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255)
    bg, fg = white, black
    # open image
    img = Image.open(fn)
    mx, my = img.size
    pix = img.load()
    # remove background
    for x in range(mx):
        for y in range(my):
            if pix[x,y] == white:
                pix[x,y] = fg
            else:
                pix[x,y] = bg
    # split text
    lx, ly = 70, 23
    for c in range(6):
        for xi in range(9):
            for yi in range(12):
                x, y = lx + c*9 + xi, ly + yi
                if pix[x, y] == fg:
                    nx = 15 + c*20 + xi
                    pix[x, y], pix[nx, y] = bg, fg
    # scale up
    r = 3
    img = img.resize((int(round(mx * r, 2)), int(round(my * r, 2))), Image.BICUBIC) # NEAREST, BILINEAR, BICUBIC
    img.save(fn + '.ppm')
    result = check_output(['ocrad', fn, + '.ppm']).strip().replace(' ', '')
    return result
```

Comment: Can you show us what is the check_Output function?

Comment: What's the value of `fn`?
Can you show more of your code before the `result =` line

Answer (score 0):

When you call `subprocess.check_output()` with *explicit* arguments as a list you *should* specify full paths to the application you are trying to run in the sub-process; no shell is invoked unless you pass `shell=True`.

This is documented in [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) which is a wrapper around [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

This should be obvious from the error you are getting from your operating system:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Which means it's likely that `ocrad` is not found in the `$PATH` so you **will have to** specify its full path.